# JPA OneToMany index missing

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

Using JPA to set up OneToMany relationship. Code is like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "draft_article", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Draft_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Article_ID"))
private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();
```

Then I go to table 'draft_article', I didn't see a column to record its list index , something wrong ? otherwise how can we know which one should be the first ?

thanks.

Comment: And using which version of JPA ? : JPA1?, JPA2?

Answer (score 1):

A List is treated as a bag by default, and thus doesn't have a column for the index. The order of the elements in the list is thus indeterminate by default.

If you need a specific order, you have to use the [`@OrderColumn` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html).

Comment: it doesn't work. Even I add @OrderColumn(name="articleIndex"), still doesn't work.

Comment: Then your JPA engine table generation has a bug. What happens if you add this column yourself to the table?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an intermediate table for managing the relationship, this table should now have these fields

---

### | "Draft_ID" | "article_id" |

This table has no column articleIndex. Why does not work @ OrderColumn (name = "articleIndex").

If you need to specify an order you must do for any column of the table. By some property of the Article class.

**Example:**

```
     @Entity public class Course {
     ...
     @ManyToMany
     @OrderBy("lastname ASC")
     public List getStudents() {...};
     ...
    }

    @Entity public class Student {
      ...
      @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
      @OrderBy // PK is assumed
      public List getCourses() {...};
      ...
    }
```